# Диалоговая программа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хотел сделать мини-программу для небольшого диалога. Суть в том, что список сравнивается с массивом, и в зависимости от того, что пишет человек, программа реагирует по-разному. Вот код:

```
line = "------------------------------"

print(line)
print()
print("[*] Get Started")
print()
print(line)

name = input("Hi, what should I call you?\n")
print("Hello, " + name + " Very nice!")
messange = {"mood": ('Not bad', 'Thumbs up', 'Nice', 'Okay', 'Great',
                          'not bad', 'thumbs up', 'thumbs up', 'nice',
                          'okay', 'great')
           }

list = []        
mood = input("What is your mood?\n")
list.append(mood)

for i in messange:
   for j in list:
      if  j != messange[i] :
         print('Hmm ...')
      else:
         print('Me too')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, не используйте переменные, которые выглядят, как функции. У Вас в коде есть переменная `list`, которая называется так же, как метод `list()`.

Во-вторых, не стоит делать списки из разных регистров. Т.е. различать great и Great: для этого есть метод `.lower()`. Использовать так: `mood = input("What is your mood?\n").lower()`. Тогда, если пользователь ввел, например, grEat, в массив list будет добавлено значение great.

В-третьих, можно не пробегать циклом массивы `list` и `messange`:

```
if mood in messange["mood"]:
    print('Me too...')
else:
    print('Hmm...')
```

Ну и дальше уже небольшой оффтоп: пожалуйста, называйте переменные так, чтобы другим это глаза не резало (у меня, например, сердце кровью обливается не от кода, а от словаря `messange`. Правильнее - `message`, `messages`, `msg`...). Не принимайте близко к сердцу и учитесь ;)

Не страшно не уметь. Страшно - даже не попытаться научиться.